# Is it possible to change the message on my WIX install success dialog

Tags: wix, wix3.10

I am new to Wix. My project uses the `WixUI_Mode` of `InstallDir`. 
I want the completion dialog to say "Installation completed" instead of "Installation successfully completed" . Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way to do that ?

Yes it is.

The WiX toolset defines the dialogs with XML. You can [customize](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface/custom-settings/) the GUI. 
But if you just want change a string you can add a `.wxl` file to your project:

```
<WixLocalization Culture="en-US" Codepage="1252" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
  <String Id="Error1707" Overridable="yes">Installation completed successfully.</String>
</WixLocalization>
```

Remove the `completed` as you like.

This overrides the localization that you find in `%WIX%\SDK\wixui`.

---

*Edit:* The `Error32` identifier is not very obvious responsible for the string in that dialog. You find all strings in the file `WixUI_en-us.wxl` in the cited folder.

Comment: Thank you . Can you please elaborate on how the error 32 is being mapped here ? please and thank you again.

Comment: If you use a VS wixproj add the code in my answer to a .wxl file in your project, e.g. `theFile.wxl`. If you compile at the command line then you have also to specify the `-loc theFile.wxl` parameter.

Comment: Yes i added the .wxl file to my VB wix project and rebuild the installer. I also checked that in 3.10 the Error1707 maps to this string so i changed that too.

Comment: i am still not sure actually. I dont see any effect of the changes i made on the wxl on my installer. Do i need to do anything else ?